# Css html custom background lines

Tags: html, css

design i'm working with have lines and icons in various sections on bg. Is there a best way to do it with css/html?
[image]

Comment: There are a lot of ways this could be done, please give us as much info as possible about your desired result: Do the icons ever change? Or move? Are they fixed in place while you scroll? Is the containing element a fixed size or responsive? Do you have a small example of the page we can see?

Comment: Can you see if [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp) helps?

Comment: While you can draw lines and display and position icons using CSS what we don’t know from what you’ve told us is what is to happen on different viewport aspect ratios.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a lot of tweaking depending on different screen resolutions, but it's at least a starting point.

Here is one done with gradients:

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  --background-color: #f5f2eb;
  --background-stripe-color: #ece2cf;
  
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(circle at 130% 120%, transparent 39.8%, var(--background-stripe-color) 40%, transparent 40.2%),
    linear-gradient(25deg, var(--background-color) 39.8%, var(--background-stripe-color) 40%, var(--background-color) 40.2%);
    
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
```

Here and another with pseudo-elements. I think this one is easier to maintain when it comes to aspect ratio, but you need to add z-index to all children within the container that has the background.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f5f2eb;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  
  overflow: hidden;
}

section::before,
section::after {
  --background-stripe-color: #ece2cf;
  
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

section::before {
  top: 60%;
  left: -100px;
  right: -100px;
  height: 2px;
  background: var(--background-stripe-color);
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}

section::after {
  --circle-size: min(150vh, 150vw);
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: var(--circle-size);
  width: var(--circle-size);
  border: 2px solid var(--background-stripe-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(70%, 60%);
}

section > * {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
```

Comment: Nice! You proved me wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS - drawing the line, circle and bridge as background images.

This snippet does this by setting the background of the actual div and before and after pseudo elements.

Positioning and sizing are done in terms of the width of the div. The snippet has the div with aspect ratio 3:1. It is responsive in that the relative positionings stay the same if the viewport is altered.

It is just a set of possible settings that could be used, with adjustment, on elements with different aspect ratios.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bg {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100vw / 3);
  /* would use aspect-ratio: 3 / 1 but older IOS does not support it */
  --bgCol: #f6f2ec;
  --lineCol: #d1ab6ba0;
  background-color: var(--bgCol);
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg id="svg_css_ex1" viewBox="0 0 300 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke="%23d1ab6ba0" stroke-width="0.25" d="M 0,30L300,100 z" /></svg>');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: 0 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bg::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  rbackground-color: pink;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 300 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <circle  fill="transparent" cx="330" cy="110" r="60" stroke="%23d1ab6ba0" stroke-width="0.25"/></svg>');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.bg::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JddA5.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vw;
  top: 75%;
  left: 90%;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```